# Job interview: Contact with interview officer.

Tags: interviewing, job-search, meetings

I am in a situation when I am looking for a job. I am invited for my first job interview.

On the invitation letter I am informed the name of the officials to whom I will have to meet. I thought it might be a good idea to get some information about them for example their field of interest, expertise.

But problem is, when I search them on the Xing or Linked in, they get the notification, will it make bad impression?

Is it very unusual to contact with them before the interview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But problem is, when I search them on the Xing or Linked in, they get
>   the notification, will it make bad impression?

How far are you going here? If you are going to try to add them as a LinkedIn contact before meeting them then yes it would make a bad impression. On the other hand, if you look through it to get some information that may be useful in the interview then it could be good. Also, be aware of whether you are researching stuff on them or are you trying to have an informal interview before the interview that may well go bad.

If you sent them a letter declaring your undying love for them then it would likely make a bad impression yes as it would seem like you are obsessed and in need of medical professional help with this issue for another extreme example here.

> Is it very unusual to contact with them before the interview?

I'd say it is unusual to contact them, yes. If you are merely looking at their profile on the site, this isn't the same as contact to my mind.

At the same time, if you are at a networking event and run into a future interview person then this can be quite good to have an opportunity to get to know the person outside of the office to some extent. Similarly if you run into someone that you had an interview a week or two ago, it can be useful to catch up on things.

Answer (score 3):

No.

People put the information on Xing and LinkedIn because they expect it to be read.

I'd be very surprised if they don't look at your profile(s) as well, first.

Comment: I know when I'm recruiting I like to see someone has attempted to view my profile, shows me they are doing some kind of research on the company before an interview.

Also I would also attempt to find the candidates profile and read that too.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but one way I get around looking at LinkedIn profiles without the profile owners getting notified is to use incognito mode in Google Chrome.